# best way to create a block of text on the left and image on the right?

Tags: css, image, text

I want to create a division with text on the left and an image on the right. The div is about 300px height. I'm trying out different ways but would prefer to follow standards for this kind of format. Thank you.

[image: this is the layout I need]

HTML

```
<div id="early">
    <h3> Napoleon's Origins </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Napoleon Bonaparte was born in his family's ancestral home on August 15, 1769.</p>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
#early {
    margin-right: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: url(../images/Napoleon_23yrs.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 160px 225px;
    line-height: 3px;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I created a div and instead of having a separate image, I made the image into a background-image and moved the content around with margin properties. For the sake of challenge, I want to do it as a div with text and image.

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS, or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div and apply display:inline-block to the paragraph tag. The image following will automatically align to the right of the text.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9mx2ddnp/)**

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
<p>Napoleon Bonaparte was born in his family's ancestral home on August 15, 1769.</p>
<img src="DD1_mini.jpg"></img>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {height:300px; width:auto; }
.content p {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

3+4 = 7 and also 5+2=7 Things are depends how simply you implement. I always use this method -

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <img src="image.jpg" class="right"></p>
```

Where css will be

```
.right { display: inline-block; float: right }
```